# Saving a copy of outlook email (.msg) to a folder after 'Send' is pressed

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have tried the codes below and it was working exactly as I wanted it to be.
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/361751-visual-basic-applications-saving-email-only-after-send-pushed.html

However, as I was creating this for other colleagues who are using different Excel version, some of my colleagues are having library error. After read around, I believe I need to use late binding instead of early binding so people with different excel version can access the function.

How to I change the code below (to late binding) so that all other version of excel users can also use the function? Copy of the working codes below.

Class Code

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents obj_OL As Outlook.Application
'
Private Sub obj_OL_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    '// For example, change pathway to suit, such as:                           //
    '// "\\Dacsrv02\rtddata\Advice\TechQueries\TRIM Emails\" & emailname
    OutMail.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & _
                           Application.PathSeparator & _
                           emailname

    '// AFTER the event has been called, explicitly release Outlook.        //
    Set obj_OL = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sub Codes

```
Option Explicit
'// Connect the declared object w/the class module                          //
Dim cls_OL As New clsOutlook
'// Declare the email msg (mail item) and emailname string as Public, so    //
'// that they can be "seen" from any procedures in the class mod.           //
Public OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Public emailname As String

Sub Email_Response()
Dim strbody As String

    '// Create our new mail item                                            //
    Set OutMail = cls_OL.obj_OL.CreateItem(0)

    '// Example substitute                                                      //
    strbody = "This is just example text"

    On Error Resume Next

    emailname = "something.msg"

    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Specific Subject"
        .body = strbody
        .Display
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (easily) support events using late binding, not in VB script. Whoever is using your code, will need to add the right version of Outlook to the project references.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, The reason I am asking for late binding was: I have created an excel with those codes in office 2007 adding Microsoft outlook object reference version 12. Another user with office 2013, was opening the file, do some work and save it (the excel automatically picked up office 2013 microsoft outlook object reference version 15). When another user login to the excel using office 2007, the macro does not run anymore as library version 15 is not found on the machine with excel 2007 (the user is not tech savvy enough to change it back to 2007 outlook reference).

Comment: Is there another way to fix this issue? I would thought late binding might be able to fix this as we do not need to choose an outlook object reference thus mitigating any issue when the user is using different office version.